# Google Cloud Platform - only allow App Engine access internally, or from Firebase hosted app

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall, firebase-hosting

I need to set up security in a Google Cloud project, so that App Engine apps can only be accessed internally by other App Engine apps in the project. I also need to allow a Firebase hosted app to access App Engine apps.

Allowing access to all App Engine apps in my project is easy. I just add an App Engine Firewall rule to allow the following IP address:

```
0.1.0.40
```

If I then set the default Firewall rule to `deny` (i.e. to prevent access to anything that doesn't connect using `0.1.0.40`), it prevents all access to our Firebase hosted app, that needs to use our Endpoints API that runs under App Engine. In other words, the Firebase hosted app doesn't connect using the IP address `0.1.0.40`. I can't specify the domain name of the Firebase app in the App Engine Firewall, as it only accepts IP addresses.

How can I allow access to the Firebase app? What techniques should I be looking at to achieve what I need?

**UPDATE**

I looked at the suggestion from @John Hanley, to use Internet Aware Proxy (IAP). This blocks access to AppEngine apps from any external domains, except for the `appspot.com` domain for my GCP project. I looked at this [IAP FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq) that has a section on 'How do I access my app from more URLs?'. I added the domain that my Firebase app is on, however the access is still blocked. How can I access the Firebase app URL using IAP?

Comment: Chris - I have not tested your scenario. You could enable IAP on App Engine. Then authenticate Firebase to App Engine with a service account. IAP will take care of the authorization.

Comment: Thanks (again) @John Hanley. How would I authenticate Firebase to App Engine with a service account though? The Firebase app is an Angular app that needs to connect to an Endpoints API running under App Engine. Can you suggest any links that explain this?

Comment: Actually, I don't know as I am not a Firebase guy. However, you could easily create a service account and use that as the "Authorization: bearer <token>" header to requests to App Engine (IAP, Endpoints, etc). Firebase probably already has an identity that IAP will recognize. This article covers your scenario: https://medium.com/@anttihavanko/firebase-authentication-with-google-cloud-endpoints-e0a2a8d5c537

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley, however this doesn't address my exact scenario. I have other apps on App Engine aside from the Endpoints API. One of those apps needs to be able to access another one by using http requests. The app that it calls can't be publicly accessible though. So, I'm trying to deny direct access to certain apps (only allowing access from other App Engine apps), but also allow access to the Endpoints API. The Endpoints API is already protected using the technique in that Medium article. The question is how to close off App Engine apps while allowing connection from a Firebase app.

Comment: Sorry Chris, out of ideas.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Wrong, no sorry I didn't find the solution I was really looking for. I always found it easier to use an API key between apps running on GCP - if that's a solution for you, you may want to use that approach?

Comment: i guess, if that's the only solution, since I haven't been able to find anything else too. Thanks!